# Loading non-contiguous floats using SSE

Tags: x86, intel, sse, simd

Is there an Intel SSE instruction which can load floats from (non contiguous) evenly spaced memory addresses?

For example given an array `A = {0, 1, 2, 3 .... n}`, I would like to load into a 128 bit register at once `{A[0], A[4], A[8], A[12]}`, followed by 
`{A[5], A[9], A[13], A[17]}`

Comment: What are you trying to do?  There may be several ways your can rewrite your algorithm to avoid gathering from non contiguous memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this kind of use case you would typically load multiple contiguous vectors and then permute them into the required arrangements using e.g. `pshufd` or `punpckldq` etc.

Note that with AVX2 in Haswell and beyond there are gathered load instructions (e.g. [_mm_i32gather_ps](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_i32gather_ps&techs=AVX2&expand=3004)), which might also be worth considering.

Comment: The Haswell [intrinsics](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-B8C3B7BF-05B6-4B3C-9E07-7707B96CEB1C.htm)

Comment: Those are the MIC intrinsics, not the Haswell intrinsics.

Comment: Haswell [intrinsics](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/f/7/c/36945). Off to get coffee now